# Combining multibib and chapterbib

Tags: natbib, subdividing, multibib

I am compiling a thesis in LaTeX using the documentclass `book`.

The thesis consists of multiple chapters with separate papers. Each chapter thus needs a separate reference list. In one of the chapters I also want to have two separate reference lists as I want one reference list for the main text and one reference list for the appendix. I am able to use `chapterbib` to get separate reference lists for the chapters. And without `chapterbib`, but by using `multibib`, I am able to get two reference lists in one chapter. However, when I try to combine the two it doesn't work.

Here is a minimum working example with `chapterbib` that gives reference for each chapter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib} 

\begin{filecontents}{chapter1.tex}
chapter1.tex:
\chapter{First chapter}
This text is first and this cite \citep{Cappelen:2007} belongs to this cite.
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chapter2.tex}
\chapter{Second chapter}
This is a reference in the second chapter \citep{Camerer:2003}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

And here is a minimum working example with `multibib` that gives two reference lists in one chapter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib} %TO ALLOW TWO REFERENCE LISTS:
\newcites{New}{Appendix references} % Create command that signals that the cite belongs to the second reference list.

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
This text is first and this cite \citep{Cappelen:2007} belongs to this cite.

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\section{Appendix}
This text is in the appendix and this cite belongs to the appendix \citepNew{Akerlof:1982}.
\bibliographystyleNew{chicago}
\bibliographyNew{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

If I attempt to combine the two examples I get the error

> illegal, another \bibdata command.

So I understand that the two are in conflict. Can anyone suggest the proper method for doing what I want?

Comment: Welcome to the forum. I think what you want to do might be rather difficult. May it be possible to typeset the appendix of the one chapter separately, and include it with `pdfpages`? Using BibLaTeX would allow you to do that relatively easily, but it takes some time getting used to (its very different from BibTeX). Might this be a possibility?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Simply adding the appendix to the rest of the document is a great idea I didn't think of. That simplifies everything and I don't think I will lose anything by doing so. Sometimes the best solution is to quit trying to solve a complex problem and find an easier problem to solve. Thank you:)